# SlimDX Direct3D11 Device Creation

Tags: c#, winforms, video-streaming, directx-11, slimdx

I have a problem in my app (WinForms [i hope it is not a problem because the link below refer to WPF]),
All my problem describes same as here :

[Fast Video Display WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906503/fast-video-display-wpf)

to display a lot of video streams, i used to work with picture box than realized that the drawing is very slow, and fps become lower.

I listen to the advised of the guy to work with Direct3D11 but
I've got a problem in the constractor :

```
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(Device, texDesc);
```

How can i send a Device ? Device is a type not an object , 
Its pop up a error to me, Im working with SlimDX ofc, Direct3D11
Really trying to figure out how to do it , or create my own device?
If there is any way else to optimze the FPS and drawing 
Or anyone have created a control who can handle this , I'll appriciate that, 
Also  , can contact me on mail : dorbenshimon1{at}gmail{dot}com
thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've sort of answered your own question - you need to pass the Device instance you've created, not the type.

Look at the examples for setting up a viewport to see how this is done.

---

As per the comments, DirectX is almost certainly not the right tool if you just want to do fast image pasting. Try something similar to this instead:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class FastImageRedraw : Panel
{
    private Image image;

    public FastImageRedraw()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        this.UpdateStyles();
    }

    public Image Image
    {
        get { return this.image; }
        set 
        {
            this.image = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.Image, e.ClipRectangle);
    }
}
```

It's very basic, but that uses GDI+ to handle redrawing the image only when you change it.

Creat an instance of it as standard with `var fastImage = new FastImageRedraw();`

Then update the image whenever it changes with `fastImage.Image = myImage;`

Comment: Yea that what I tough about, the problem is I've tried to create a instance of Deivce with Direct3D11 And dont know how to do it, Can u guide me please / where I can find these examples?

Comment: Well I am not so pro , or have a big understanding in directX (guess I should menition that on the start)
Maybe there already a Control I can use that using SlimDX and he is optimzied to draw a image?

Comment: SlimDX and DX development generally are complicated, and almost certainly not needed to simply paste some images. |You probably want to look into GDI, I'll update my answer to include some basic info.

Comment: Thanks, but i want to display something like 10 videos from IP cams in 25 FPS 
This code will work ?

Comment: Try it, you'll soon have your answer. It entirely depends on the PC running it of course, but I wouldn't have thought it would be a problem on an average PC with a dedicated graphics card.