# How to draw rectangle on JPG in C# for WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image-processing

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have folder with a series of jpgs, which are frames of video that have been converted into jpgs. I made some code that iterates through them and displays them.

I am trying to draw a green box on a JPG image from C#. The Hight, Width, XC and YC are in a XML I just access the data there for each frame. I got it to work using a bitmap but then to display it in WPF I have to convert it into a bitmapImage first. The problem is it takes way to long. I want the video to be played at 25 fps. so all the processing needs to happen under 40 ms. Right now it takes anywhere between .01 and .3 seconds to displays the new image.

Here is the code I have so far-

```
public void UpdateImage(string imageName, int[] boxData)
{


    // imageName is the file path the image
    Bitmap oldImage = new Bitmap(imageName);


    // if objects are detected
    if (boxData.Length != 0)
    {
        // transforms x and y cords to align box better to light
        int newXC = boxData[0] - (boxData[2] / 2);
        int newYC = boxData[1] - (boxData[3] / 2);

        // ensures cords are not negative
        if (newXC < 0)
            newXC = 0;
        if (newYC < 0)
            newYC = 0;

        // uses the DrawRectangleBorder to draw rectangles 
        Bitmap newImage = DrawRectangleBorder(oldImage, new Rectangle(new System.Drawing.Point(newXC, newYC), new System.Drawing.Size(boxData[2], boxData[3])), Color.Green);

        // converts Bitmap to BitmapImage
        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            newImage.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
            memory.Position = 0;
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
            bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();
            ImportImage.Source = bitmapImage;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        Bitmap newImage = oldImage;

        // converts Bitmap to BitmapImage
        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            newImage.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
            memory.Position = 0;
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
            bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();
            ImportImage.Source = bitmapImage;
        }
    }
}
```

The DrawRectangleBorder Method-

```
private static Bitmap DrawRectangleBorder(Bitmap image, Rectangle rectangle, Color colour)
{

    // makes new blank Bitmap from the old ones width and height
    Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);

    // opens up the blank bit
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap))
        graphics.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height),
            new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    // what actually draws the rectangles
    for (Int32 x = rectangle.Location.X; x <= rectangle.Right && x < image.Width; x++)
        for (Int32 y = rectangle.Location.Y; y <= rectangle.Bottom && y < image.Height; y++)
            if (y == rectangle.Location.Y || y == rectangle.Bottom || x == rectangle.Location.X || x == rectangle.Right)
                newBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, colour);

    return newBitmap;
}
```

Here is what one of the pictures look like, they are 640 by 480 resolution-
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiocC.jpg
Any help would be great!

Comment: How long does your current strategy take

Comment: Could you post one of you images?  Can you not buffer this operation (ie load and edit the frames up front and then display the video after you are finished editing?)

Comment: Is there any image processing going into placing the rectangles or are they at a static position

Comment: I could also give a link to .zip folder of JPGs

Comment: Do you need the actual images to have the rectangles added to them (ie edit the video) or are you just trying to make it so that the rectangle appears on the video?  Like can you just overlay a rectangle object in front of the image and move that around instead of fiddling with graphics or the image at all?

Comment: Yes that would work, I just need to see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simplify your code by using this XAML

```
<Canvas>
    <Image x:Name="ImportImage"/>
    <Path x:Name="ObjectBox"
          Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ImportImage}"
          Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ImportImage}"
          Stretch="None" Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="1"/>
</Canvas>
```

with an UpdateImage method like this:

```
public void UpdateImage(string imagePath, int[] boxData)
{
    ImportImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath));

    var boxes = new GeometryGroup();

    for (int i = 0; i <= boxData.Length - 4; i += 4)
    {
        int width = boxData[i + 2];
        int height = boxData[i + 3];
        int x = boxData[i] - width / 2;
        int y = boxData[i + 1] - height / 2;

        boxes.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(x, y, width, height)));
    }

    ObjectBox.Data = boxes;
}
```

Comment: That works fantastic! But what if I need to draw multiple boxes at the same time or stop it from drawing outside of the image?

Comment: You may create a GeometryGroup with multiple RectangleGeometries.  To avoid drawing outside, see the additional properties on the Path element.

Comment: Would that GeometryGroup add rectangles dynamically?

Comment: Take a look at its documentation. It has a Children property where you add RectangleGeometries (or other Geometries). Create a new GeometryGroup each time the collection of boxes changes.

Comment: So I would only need to have one more element in my xaml or if I need to draw 3 rectangles I would have to make three new elements?

Comment: One Path with a GeometryGroup as Data. 3 RectangleGeometries in the GeometryGroup's Children, set in the UpdateImage method. Are these additional boxes in the `boxData` argument?

Comment: What if the number of rectangles need changes as the program runs? Like sometimes 3 rectangles are needed, other times one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237254/discussion-between-chaseratliff-and-clemens).

Comment: See the edit - in case there are multiple boxes in the boxData argument.

Answer (score 1):

here is a rough demo of using a rectangle overlaid in front of an image and controlling its position and size.  Sorry, never shared wpf on SO before, but think this code is all you need.  I tested the time and it can go well below 40 ms (but I am not updating the image at all, just the rectangle overlay.  In case it is needed, I also found this [Fast Video Display WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906503/fast-video-display-wpf) but ya, did not implement it or test it out.

".cs"

```
namespace ImageStreamer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        long lastTime = 0;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0,0,25);
            stopWatch.Start();

        }

        private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            targetRect.Margin = new Thickness(targetRect.Margin.Left+1, targetRect.Margin.Top+1,0,0);
            targetRect.Width += 1;
            targetRect.Height += 1;
            Trace.WriteLine(lastTime - stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            lastTime = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }

        private void Grid_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

"xaml"

```
<Window x:Class="ImageStreamer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageStreamer"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Initialized="Grid_Initialized">
        <Image x:Name="imgBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="265" Margin="166,87,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="512" Source="/ZiocC.jpg"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="targetRect" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="49" Margin="323,228,0,0" Stroke="Red" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="113" StrokeThickness="5"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I think the slow part is loading the image.

Comment: Do you know if loading or drawing the image is the limiting factor: ie if you load all the images into an array before playing the video and then play it.

Comment: It is both, when nothing is being drawn its like .015 seconds. but upwards of .3 when I'm drawing the rectangle.

Comment: Wait so you can show the frames reliably at 0.015?

Comment: Not all, .015 is the lowest. Average is around .15.